# Regex match letters not inside single quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match all charecters and digits(\w) inside the string which not inside the single quote (\')

For instance I have string:

```
param : 'test' .param4 'zzzz' param8 * 'rrrr'
```

from that string I need to get:

```
- param
- param4
- param8
```

Thx for any advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
/(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)\b\w+\b/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wK4wZ5/1)

This regex will match a word if that word is outside single quotes by using a lookahead to make sure there are even number of quotes after each word. This assumes unescaped quotes are balanced.

**Code:**

```
var re = /(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)\b\w+\b/gm; 
var str = 'param : \'test\' .param4 \'zzzz\' param8 * \'rrrr\' class2.class3*dsaasd';
var m;
var result;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    res.push(m[0]);
}

console.log(result);
```